# CkEditor toolbar group options to dropdown

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, ckeditor, toolbar

I have a question about grouping some CkEditor toolbar options to dropdown menu. For example, if I add this option ['JustifyLeft', 'JustifyCenter', 'JustifyRight', 'JustifyBlock'] to toolbar, I get 4 buttons. Since I think this is a waste od space in toolbar, I would like to put all 4 options to dropdown - that only 1 (selected) would be visible.

Is that even possible? I found this solution

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor', {
    plugins: 'wysiwygarea,sourcearea,basicstyles,toolbar,menu,menubutton,justify',
    on: {
        pluginsLoaded: function() {
            var editor = this,
                items = {};

            editor.addMenuGroup( 'some_group' );

            items.justifyleft = {
                label: editor.lang.justify.left,
                group: 'some_group',
                command: 'justifyleft',
                order: 1
            };

            items.justifyright = {
                label: editor.lang.justify.right,
                group: 'some_group',
                command: 'justifyright',
                order: 2
            };

            editor.addMenuItems( items );

            editor.ui.add( 'Groupped', CKEDITOR.UI_MENUBUTTON, {
                label: 'Groupped justify',
                // Disable in source mode.
                modes: { 
                    wysiwyg: 1 
                },
                icon: 'JustifyLeft',
                onMenu: function() {
                    var active = {};

                    // Make all items active.
                    for ( var p in items )
                        active[ p ] = CKEDITOR.TRISTATE_OFF;

                    return active;
                }
            } );                       
        }
    }
} );
```

on http://jsfiddle.net/oleq/vmYCF/, but as you can see, now I have both options - 4 buttons + drop down, so that is not acceptable for me. And also in that case, I cannot set other toolbars ( and I don't know why not).

Thanks for any help

Best Regards

Comment: Were you ever able to figure this out?

Answer (score 4):

I was able to figure this out, though it's kinda hacky. I converted that code in your post into a plugin, then added this to the CSS.

```css
.cke_button__justifyleft, 
.cke_button__justifyright, 
.cke_button__justifycenter,
.cke_button__justifyblock {
    display: none !important;
}
```

For whatever reason, the plugin requires the justify plugin to be loaded and added to the toolbar for the dropdown icons in the justifygroup plugin to show up correctly. Hiding the extra 4 buttons does the trick.

Here's the plugin:

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.add( 'justifygroup', {
    // jscs:disable maximumLineLength
    requires: "wysiwygarea,basicstyles,toolbar,menu,menubutton,justify",
    lang: 'af,ar,bg,bn,bs,ca,cs,cy,da,de,el,en,en-au,en-ca,en-gb,eo,es,et,eu,fa,fi,fo,fr,fr-ca,gl,gu,he,hi,hr,hu,id,is,it,ja,ka,km,ko,ku,lt,lv,mk,mn,ms,nb,nl,no,pl,pt,pt-br,ro,ru,si,sk,sl,sq,sr,sr-latn,sv,th,tr,tt,ug,uk,vi,zh,zh-cn', // %REMOVE_LINE_CORE%
    // jscs:enable maximumLineLength
    hidpi: true, // %REMOVE_LINE_CORE%
    tabToOpen:null,
    init: function( editor ) {
        if ( editor.blockless )
            return;

        items = {};

        editor.addMenuGroup( 'some_group' );

        items.justifyleft = {
            label: editor.lang.justify.left,
            group: 'some_group',
            command: 'justifyleft',
            order: 1
        };
        items.justifycenter = {
            label: editor.lang.justify.center,
            group: 'some_group',
            command: 'justifycenter',
            order: 2
        };

        items.justifyright = {
            label: editor.lang.justify.right,
            group: 'some_group',
            command: 'justifyright',
            order: 3
        };

        items.justifyblock = {
            label: editor.lang.justify.block,
            group: 'some_group',
            command: 'justifyblock',
            order: 4
        };

        if (editor.addMenuItems) {
            editor.addMenuItems( items );
        }

        editor.ui.add( 'Grouped', CKEDITOR.UI_MENUBUTTON, {
            label: 'Grouped justify',
            icon: 'JustifyLeft',
            toolbar: "align",
            modes: { 
                wysiwyg: 1 
            },
            onMenu: function() {
                var active = {};

                // Make all items active.
                for ( var p in items )
                    active[ p ] = CKEDITOR.TRISTATE_OFF;

                return active;
            }
        } );                       
    }
} );
```